# Google Maps show location history where I've never even been

Tags: google-maps, google-location-history

I have a Samsung Galaxy Core Prime and it has Google Maps downloaded on it as well as other Google apps. My husband went through my phone and in the Google Maps app, under timeline, apparently it showed that I had actually went to several places on days when I had *never* left the house, but the worse part is that it's saying I've been to places I've *never* even been.

This whole situation is frustrating because I love my husband *very* much but now he is completely convinced that I'm cheating on him, *and I'm not*; there has to be someone out there that can explain this total mess cause my husband doesn't believe a word I say.

Please help me figure this mess out and convince my husband that I'm not lying and in definitely not cheating!

Comment: Actually Google maps doesn't record your location from time to time, but Google Now does. Someone else might have been using the phone  if it's not you.

Comment: @MANI Actually, Google Maps *does* record your location.  You can see the tracking history at https://www.google.com/maps/timeline

Comment: I know you can go to Google.com/naps/timeline to see tracking history, that's why all this is so confusing cause we both went there and checked everything out but as I said e

Comment: @Micheleclark My original comment was in response to the other comment that said that Maps doesn't track you.

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible reasons that places could show up inaccurately in the Google Maps tracking.

- If your device is indoors, it will not have a good GPS signal (or possibly have no GPS signal at all) and will have to use less accurate location methods. Each of those methods has problems, some of which are discussed below.
- If your device is trying to locate itself using WiFi networks (now called "WiFi Positioning System" or "WiPS" for short), it looks for nearby WiFi networks that Google knows about and then uses the locations that Google has on record for those networks as a way to determine your approximate location.  However, that means that if someone from a particular area moved into your area and Google has not updated their database, then Google's database will think that you are in the area where that person's WiFi network used to be.
- If your device is trying to locate itself by searching for nearby cellphone towers, it could determine that it is anywhere in a large area in which those towers can be detected. The effective range of a cell phone tower could be anything between 1 and 45 miles, depending on how dense your area is.  That means that the numbers could be up to that far off if they only came from cell tower data.
- Even if you do have a good GPS signal, Google will sometimes "snap" your location to a nearby "point of interest" if you drive by.  I don't know exactly how far away this snapping can happen, but I have seen it make some pretty bad guesses.

Here's one extreme example that I just read about: [People keep going to this home looking for their lost phones and nobody knows why](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2016/01/26/people-keep-going-to-this-home-looking-for-their-lost-phones-and-nobody-knows-why/).

In the end, the fact is that the location-tracking systems available on consumer devices today are not that accurate.  I worked from home today because of the "Snowzilla" blizzard on the US East Coast, and left home twice to go to the library and run one errand, but my location history shows me being up to a mile further away from home than any of the locations which I visited. (I am actually working next door to [a research group](http://www.mindlab.umd.edu/) at the University of Maryland that is working on more-accurate location technologies, but it will be a while before any of them are on the market.)

Answer (score 1):

Other than what @MosheKatz said in his answer another point you may have to consider is that whether your Google account is being used only on your Samsung Galaxy Core Prime.

I was surprised to see my timeline jumping across countries and quickly realised that my relative who has borrowed my Nexus tablet is producing these results. Being a close relative I did not mind handing over the tablet with my account in sync.

You try to sign out of all locations by visiting your Gmail account in a computer, then click on the `Details` link at the bottom right corner of the screen and then sign out from all web sessions by clicking a button that says so in the popup.

Also, you can visit [Google Play Store account](https://play.google.com/settings) in a computer and click on the settings (a button with a cog wheel on top right). This opens up the devices in which your account is being used. If it list more than one phone/tablet then it confirms my assumption.

Additionally, explain your partner that to trust you more than the data/statistics or Google for that matter. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same experience. I saw my husbands timeline history on google maps and was accusing him of being places that google maps was showing in his location history. SO, I set up the app on my own phone and would check my timeline. To my surprise it also showed me being places that I never went and on days that I never left my house! Maybe have him set it up on his phone so that he can see you are telling him the truth.